# How do I format a cell as hyperlink using Excel's COM API?

Tags: excel, add-in

I have an Excel AddIn (C# IExtensibility) and need to mark a cell as having the hyperlink format. What is the best way to do this?

I think what I need to do is set a cell to the builtin style 8. But if I get Range.Style - there is no way to set the style builtin id. How can I do this?

??? - thanks - dave

Answer (score -1):

```
Range("A1").Style = "Hyperlink"
```

Note that this will only give the cell the illusion of looking like a hyperlink. To actually make it have a hyperlink, you need to go:

```
Sheet(1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A1"),  _
    Address:="http://www.google.com", _
    TextToDisplay:="www.google.com"
```

Comment: That gave me the error: COMException: Style Hyperlink not found. If I created a hyperlink first, then this works fine. But does not work if no hyperlink style has been used yet. Is there a way to force the creation of that style?

Comment: Don't know. This works automatically when using VBA in excel, I suppose this is one of those things that work just a bit differently when done in .Net. It's certainly one of the built-in styles in Excel 2007 (visible in the styles ribbon item). Maybe built-in styles aren't available to the .Net API? Maybe you're using the Excel 2003 API?

Comment: ...or maybe you should reply only if you KNOW the answer? in requested .NET and not VBA